# Messages sent over socket not being printed on the receiving side

Tags: java, network-programming

I am currently learning Java, and I tried to make a simple chat program, which communicates between a server and a client. My problem is that the two programs connect properly to each other, but send messages do not get print out. I do not know whether it is the sending or receiving part. Do not judge my class naming, it is just temporarily.

The client-side part of receiving:

```
InputStream is = chatterSock.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = chatterSock.getOutputStream();
    Thread readThread = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
                out.append(newLine);
            }

            chatter.print("<p>" + out.toString() + "</p>");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            chatter.printWarning("Connection lost");
        }

    }
```

The server-side part is pretty similar.

To send messages I just run

```
<Socket>.getOutputStream().write(<String>.getBytes());
```

I already tried some other posts from stackoverflow, but did not find a way that works. Thanks for your help!

Edit: here is the server side:

```
InputStream is = chatterSock.getInputStream();
OutputStream os = chatterSock.getOutputStream();

Thread readThread = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
                out.append(newLine);
            }
            overlord.print("<p>" + out.toString() + "</p>");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            overlord.chatterSockList.remove(overlord.chatterSockList.indexOf(chatterSock));
            overlord.printWarning("Connection to " + chatterSock.getInetAddress() + " lost");
            overlord.sendToAll(("User " + username + " disconnected."));
        }
    }

});
```

Edit: The message gets send here:

```
sendButton.addActionListener(e -> {

    try {
        chatterSock.getOutputStream().write((messageArea.getText()+"\n").getBytes());
        messageArea.setText("");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        printWarning("Connection lost"); //TODO heartbeat
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your string contain a `\n`?

Comment: Depending on the user input.Just tested it. But works neither with not without newline...

Comment: Can you add the code for your server side? There are several potential problems here. And since you said they were similar, I'm also not sure where you have the `write()` placed.

Comment: While it's probably not related to your problem, you're using the default platform charset both when writing (`getBytes` with no argument) and reading (`InputStreamReader` constructor with only one argument). If the default charset on the client and server are different, text can get garbled.

Comment: If the sender doesn't send a newline, the receiver will wait forever in the `readLine()` method.

Comment: I added \n to the string that is send, but it does not help

Comment: OK, so where *are* you using that `write`? In no place do I see anything written to the socket.

Comment: It is now included to the post. i just don't wanted to post the whole source code but just the part I thought contains the problem

Comment: if I recall my java correctly, your reader.readLine() is NEVER going to be null until you close the connection.  You aren't printing anything until the connection is closed.  Try putting the print statement inside the inner while loop.

Comment: It works! Thanks! If you would have posted it as an answer I would accept it :)

Comment: Get rid of the outer loop. The inner loop reads until end of stream: there's no point in any further reading after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Russell Uhl mentions in his comment, a read loop whose termination condition is `reader.readLine()) != null` is only going to terminate when the output stream is closed.

If the output stream is not closed, that call simply waits for new information, and shall continue to do so indefinitely.

It is also going to wait indefinitely if you don't send over a newline, which is why you were told to add it to your write command.

It would be best to process each line you read separately, rather than trying to append them to a buffer and output them all together. Do the processing inside the loop.

And probably it's also a good idea to add some button to your GUI to terminate the chat. It will disable the rest of the GUI and close the output stream, which in turn will cause the `readLine()` to return null, and the loop to terminate properly.

Comment: The receive and and where in own threads. But with the newline and the print command in the inner while loop of works now.